# Is there any mistake while writing ImportValue function in CloudFormation.yaml file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

```
xxx:
 Type: "AWS::ApiGateWay::Authorizer"
 DependsOn:
  - xxxxx
 Properties:
  AuthResultInSecs: "300"
  AuthUri:
   Fn::Sub:
   - "arn:aws:apigateway:xxx"
   - authLambdaArn: !ImportValue iml-authorizer-${Environment}
```

I'm getting following error while deploying -
"No export named iml-authorizer-${Environment} found"

Why it's not importing value of Environment variable?

I tried checking for any syntax error which I didn't found. What else it can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Sub` with `ImportValue` as explained in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html):

```
xxx:
 Type: "AWS::ApiGateWay::Authorizer"
 DependsOn:
  - xxxxx
 Properties:
  AuthResultInSecs: "300"
  AuthUri:
   Fn::Sub:
   - "arn:aws:apigateway:xxx"
   - authLambdaArn: 
        Fn::ImportValue:
            !Sub "iml-authorizer-${Environment}"
```